# Nextjs getServerSideProps substitutes a param for `window-provider.js.map` and runs twice

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am running a `getServerSideProps` in my page that is nested in a following way:

`/pages/manage/[tokenType]/[address]`

For some reason in local dev when visiting `http://localhost:3000/manage/ERC721/0x8ED2a85815412fD1a8E48F527bc99C259aAE758D` the `getServerSideProps` is executed twice and for the first query the params are correct:

```
query: {
    tokenType: 'ERC721',
    address: '0x8ED2a85815412fD1a8E48F527bc99C259aAE758D'
  },
resolvedUrl: '/manage/ERC721/0x8ED2a85815412fD1a8E48F527bc99C259aAE758D',
params: {
    tokenType: 'ERC721',
    address: '0x8ED2a85815412fD1a8E48F527bc99C259aAE758D'
  }
```

but when it runs the second time, it gets changed to:

```
query: { tokenType: 'ERC721', address: 'window-provider.js.map' },
resolvedUrl: '/manage/ERC721/window-provider.js.map',
params: { tokenType: 'ERC721', address: 'window-provider.js.map' },
```

I have no idea why what happens, any thoughts?

EDIT: Killing the process did not help.

EDIT: Restarting my machine removed the issue. but what happened? we may never know

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.